# Determine if a Google Play Billing Subscrition Purchase is inital or renewal

Tags: android, in-app-subscription

This question is relative to the android/client side API. Per Google documentation, *["All initial subscription purchases need to be acknowledged. Subscription renewals don't need to be acknowledged."](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate)*

For any particular purchase, how does one determine if it is inital or renewal?

While `queryPurchasesAsync` returns a `PurchaseList`, the list doesn't contain a field identifying the purchase as inital. Is this something I can/need to track on the GPBL client side?

I have yet to get the server-side API to function due to service account/permission issues. The API access/permissions has me totally confused. I have yet to locate any documentation on how to link my app and configure access using the current dashboard. Nothing makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

For the newest v5/v6 Billing Library version, there is a specific field for the subscription product info: [getBillingCycleCount](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/ProductDetails.PricingPhase#getBillingCycleCount()). It gets you the information about periods of subscription applied

Comment: BTW, I'm using v6.0.1 of the library. My understanding is the `billingCycleCount` indicates the number of cycles for which a billing period is applied, not a running counter. Throughout my testing (simple prepaid and renewing base plans), the billingCycleCount has always equaled 0. The documentation also highlights: 
"Note: Set to 0 for ProductDetails.RecurrenceMode.INFINITE_RECURRING and ProductDetails.RecurrenceMode.NON_RECURRING".